# Posting dynamic table using ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm reading data from new tables using a SQL returning a datatable and able to show it in a view using the datatable as a model but the post/submit does not return anything, except in the `HttpContext.Request.Form`.

The new table column names cannot be determined except using SQL, so cannot use a model

```
// GET: /Home/
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit()
{
    var conn = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();
    await conn.OpenAsync();

    var command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM NewTable";

    var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);

    dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[]
                        { 
                             dt.Columns["id"], 
                             dt.Columns["idd"], 
                             dt.Columns["idf"] 
                        };

    return View(dt);
}


@using System.Data
@model DataTable
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Edit</title>
  

</head>
<body>
    <form asp-controller="Dynam" asp-action="Edit" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
                {
                    <td>@column.ColumnName</td>
                }
            </tr>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var row = Model.Rows[i];
                <tr>
                    @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
                    {
                        if (column.ColumnName == "id")
                        {
                            @Html.Hidden(column.ColumnName, row[column.ColumnName] )
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td>@Html.TextBox(column.ColumnName + "[" + i.ToString() + "]", row[column.ColumnName])</td>
                        }
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </form>

    <div></div>
</body>
</html>


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(DataTable dt)
{
    var commandText = "UPDATE MyTable SET @NewColumn = ('123xyz') " +
                      "WHERE Id = @Id AND Idd = @Idd AND Idf = @IDF";
    var first = true;

    foreach (string key in HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys)
    {
        // build sql for update
```

Answer (score 0):

For example I create a model like this

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace WebMvcApp.Models
{
    public class DynamicTable
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Dictionary<string, string>> properties { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I set all the rows as a List and all of the Column as a Dictionary. Then I create a test data like this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var map1 = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "key1", "valueA1" },
        { "key2", "valueA2" },
        { "key3", "valueA3" }
    };
    var map2 = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "key1", "valueB1" },
        { "key2", "valueB2" },
        { "key3", "valueB3" }
    };
    var table = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>
    {
        map1,
        map2
    };
    var entity = new DynamicTable
    {
        name = "table1",
        properties = table
    };
    return View(entity);
}
```

Then I can deal with it in my view like this:

```
@model DynamicTable

<table>
    <tr>

        @foreach (var entry in Model.properties[0])
        {
            <td>@entry.Key</td>
        }
    </tr>
    @{
        foreach (var item in Model.properties)
        {
            <tr>
            @foreach(var keypair in item)
                {
                    <td>@keypair.Value</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers Mr Wang,  that looks like a good way to get it into a model and on screen. I wrapped it in a form and still don't get any data back in the DynamicTable?
    @model DynamicTable 
<form id="XForm" asp-action="indexTwo" asp-controller="Dynam"  method="post">        [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> IndexTwo( DynamicTable s)                                       
Should I change to using ajax?

Comment: Ajax is good as well, and if you are using MVC, I think using Model or ViewModel to bring  data to the view is also a good choice, it's all above you. According the `form` in your response, I think ajax is more suitable for this scenario as you need to deal with the response data from the post request.